# Is it possible to reset the runspace in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

One of the features of [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) is the ability to reset the [Powershell Runspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.aspx) as demonstrated in [this article](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/clearing-powershell-runspace-before-debugging/) and [this article](http://laez.nl/powergui-script-editor-empty-your-runspace/). Is it possible to do this in PowerShell ISE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a module called "ISE Session Tools" to do this a few months back. Essentially the runspace in ISE is equated to a "Tab" container, of which its child documents share the runspace. My script looks at the current open files, remembers them, creates a new Tab (runspace) and closes the old one, then adds the files you had open to the new Tab. Other features:

- AutoSaving of current session (files open in current tab.)

This can be disabled and manually controlled if desired.

- Prompt to reload last session on ISE open

A hint is shown to you reminding you of some of the files you had open. Press `<enter>` to accept the default of “Yes, reload my last session.”

- **Restarting of the current tab**

Essentially cleaning memory and keeping your files open in the editor. You get prompted for this action. Press `<enter>` to accept default of “Yes, restart this tab.”

All commands available under “Add-ons” menu for the mouse-fixated. These commands are also bound to hot-keys.

See: http://nivot.org/post/2011/02/14/MakingWindowsPowerShellISEGoodEnough

---

EDIT: For the time being, the blog's download link for the *ISE Session Tools* is broken. The Internet Archive still has [a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20110424230510/http://www.nivot.org/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/Making-Windows-PowerShell-ISE-Good-Enou_C345/IseSessionTools.zip).

Comment: That looks awesome. Are you releasing that under an OSS license?

Comment: If it's on my blog, it's whatever license you want.

Comment: Not that I don't agree that this is cool, and very useful, but I find it very annoying when something happens to the cli and by restarting anything I loose my _undo_ history.

Answer (score 14):

(I am using PowerShell V3 ISE on the Win8 Release Preview)
You can use File>New PowerShell tab to create a new PowerShell runspace inside the ISE