# Clearing ISE Powershell environment / debugging methodology

Tags: debugging, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

When writing a powershell script in ISE I have something analogous to (which I execute with <kbd>F5</kbd>):

```
Function DoSomethingNow
{
    "What am I doing?"
}

DoSomethingNow
```

The problem is if I rename or remove `DoSomethingNow` it is still available in the session.  This causes confusion in that my script will continue to work, whereas I would expect an error in the absence of the function.

I can only assume I need to clear the session after each round of debugging, however it would appear this is only possible by restarting ISE (therefore restarting the powershell session).

Therefore I ask:

- Is it possible to clear the session so that `DoSomethingNow` is no longer in scope?
- What is the 'correct' way to debug and execute powershell scripts repeatedly?
- Perhaps I'm not using ISE the correct way?

I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reset the runspace in Powershell ISE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338395/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-runspace-in-powershell-ise)

Answer (score 3):

You can "delete" the function with `Remove-Item` and the `Function` `PSDrive`

`Remove-Item Function:\DoSomethingNow`

If you add this to the end of your script & remove each function (only in debug situations, I hope), you'll get a fresh start each time. You can do similar for aliases & environment variables, if you're setting those.

You may also want to look at `$Error.Clear()` to clear out any entries in the `$Error` object, as well as [`Remove-Variable`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849935.aspx) (you can probably guess what this one does).

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but it seems a hassle to have to clear everything up like this?  Has .net become to ingrained in me?  Also why would you only clear these out in debug situations?

Comment: It's not so much .Net vs. Powershell (since PoSH *is* .Net) as it is compiled program vs. console session/environment. When you exit a compiled program, everything about its state that isn't persisted elsewhere evaporates. Within a console session, everything you do sticks around until you clear it, or kill the whole session - you're working *within* a compiled program, in a way.

Comment: So why isn't there a decent way to clear sessions at the end of your script?  Am I approaching scripting development incorrectly?

Comment: Have a look at [this SO post on the same subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338395/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-runspace-in-powershell-ise). Other script IDEs can do it, but it's not a native feature of the ISE.