# Powershell IDE: How to restart interactive shell to clear all variables without leaving Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Let's say I've been using Powershell ISE for a while and my environment space is starting to get dirty, and I need to restart the interactive shell... I don't want to close my editor and reopen it.  How to restart powershell ISE interactive shell to clear all variables without closing and reopening the Powershell ISE?

[image]

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7338395/7571258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a new PowerShell tab that starts as if it was a fresh PowerShell session.

Answer (score 7):

First, the obligatory notice:

- The **PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)** and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably **not being able to run [PowerShell (Core) 6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**.
- The **actively developed editor** that offers the best PowerShell development experience, **across PowerShell editions and platforms**, is **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**, combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

---

**ISE**:

**[Colin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65131861/45375) is a pragmatic solution: open a *new tab* and close the old one.**

However, that **new session invariably retains the *environment variables* of the old one**, because the  ISE hosts the PowerShell SDK *in-process* rather than running `powershell.exe` as a *child process*.

To restart a session in the *current* tab you would therefore have to instruct the hosted [`System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) instance to discard its current runspace and create a new one - and I'm not aware of a way to do this.

Even if it were possible, however, the *environment variables* - which exist at the level of the *process* that runs the ISE - would be retained.

---

**Visual Studio Code**:

It *is* possible to **start a new session in the *current* tab** and to do so  ***without* inheriting the old session's environment variables**:

While the integrated terminal running is running the [PowerShell Integrated Console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375), which the PowerShell extension comes with - which is the equivalent of the console pane in the ISE - you can **kill the current instance by clicking the trash-can icon** in the toolbar of the terminal panel as shown below.

After doing so, **you're prompted for starting a *new* session**, which runs in a new `powershell.exe` / `pwsh` *child process*.

[image: kill the running shell in VS Code]

Alternatively - and **preferably** - **you can configure the PowerShell extension to *automatically* start a new session *whenever you start a new debugging session***, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out:

- Either: Open the Settings (<kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>) view, search for `powershell temporary` and turn on the `PowerShell > Debugging: Create Temporary Integrated Console` setting.
- Or: Add `"powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true` directly to your `settings.json` file.

This automatically starts a new, temporary PowerShell Integrated Console *for each debugging session*, which remains open until you start the next debugging session, at which point a new temporary console simply replaces the old one.

- Curiously, as of extension version `2022.11.0`, you cannot `exit` out of a PowerShell Integrated Console, but you can use the trash-can icon or `Stop-Process -Id $PID` to kill it, if needed, which in the case of a *temporary* console will (commendably) *not* prompt you to restart it; instead, the next debugging session will create a new, temporary console on demand.

**This configuration avoids a major pitfall that afflicts the ISE *invariably*** (and may in part be what prompted the question) as well as the PowerShell extension's *default* configuration:

- There, the code runs dot-sourced, i.e. directly in the top-level scope of the same session, so that **the state left behind by earlier debugging runs can interfere with subsequent debugging runs**; for instance, create a script with content `(++$i)` and run it repeatedly - you'll see that `$i` increments every time, across runs.
- Starting a new session for every debugging run avoids this problem.

Comment: @BillMoore: Fair point; they actually did implement an obsolescence warning of sorts for the Windows PowerShell _console_, where you now get a suggestion to try PowerShell [Core] instead on startup. If you feel inspired, you can suggest implementing something similar for the ISE [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell), though I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Works great and will save me a bunch of time and frustration. The delay as the new terminal is opening is no worse than the compilation step when debugging in Visual Studio with other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Try either 1 of below to clear variable memory , it shall help

```
exit     # Exit will quit from Powershell. 


Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0 # this will kill all the memory on current session
```

Comment: Thumbs up, so far this works for me.`                                                                                                                                 
PSVersion: 5.1.19041.1682, 
PSCompatibleVersions: {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
`